# Unable to authenticate to RavenDB server on local network

Tags: ravendb

I am attempting to connect to RavenDB on **Server2** from **Server1**.

On **Server2** I have created a new user "RavenDBUser" and granted them read/write access to the Database directory within the RavenDB installation.

I am running RavenDB as the windows service on port 8080.

On **Server1** I have set the connection string for my application to:

```
Url=http://server2:8080;Database=MyDatabase;Domain=server2;user=RavenDBUser;password=mypassword;
```

When I run my application, I get a 403, forbidden error.

However, I *am* able to connect to the RavenDB Studio from **Server1** and view "MyDatabase" after authenticating as "RavenDBUser".

The error details can be seen below:

> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.] 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8522396
>   Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadJsonInternal(Func`1
>   getResponse) +805
>
>   Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson() +587
>
>   Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectPutIndex(String name,
>   String operationUrl, Boolean overwrite, IndexDefinition definition)
>   +774    Raven.Client.Connection.<>c__DisplayClass50.<PutIndex>b__4f(String
>   operationUrl) +36
>
>   Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.TryOperation(Func`2
>   operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result) +194
>   Raven.Client.Connection.ReplicationInformer.ExecuteWithReplication(String
>   method, String primaryUrl, Int32 currentRequest, Int32
>   currentReadStripingBase, Func`2 operation) +526
>
>   Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication(String
>   method, Func`2 operation) +138
>   Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask.Execute(IDatabaseCommands
>   databaseCommands, DocumentConvention documentConvention) +86
>   Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(ExportProvider
>   catalogToGetnIndexingTasksFrom, IDatabaseCommands databaseCommands,
>   DocumentConvention conventions) +108
>   MyApp.CMSRegistry.InitializeStore() +380    MyApp.CMSRegistry..ctor()
>   +66

Comment: So to confirm,  you can access it via the browser?

Comment: Yes. I am prompted for authenticate and can successfully authenticate as the "Server2\RavenDBUser" user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the missing piece was that you have to explicitly enable the windows user/group in the RavenDB system database configuration.

The not so easy to find docs for doing this can be found at http://ravendb.net/docs/studio/multi-database about 3/4 down the page.